# Unity - No public constructor is available for type MVCTeste.Repository.IEmpresaService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, injeção-de-dependência

Estou usando UNITY para fazer injeção de dependência .net framework 4.5, configurei tudo mais na hora de rodar é apresenta o erro : No public constructor is available for type MVCTeste.Repository.IEmpresaService. Segue o código:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IEmpresaService, EmpresaService>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}

public interface IEmpresaService
{
    Task Add(Empresa empresa);
    Task Update(Empresa empresa);
    Task Delete(int? id);
    Task<Empresa[]> GetEmpresas();
    Task<Empresa> GetEmpresaById(int? id);
}

public class EmpresaService : IEmpresaService
{
    private readonly MVCTesteContext _context;

    public EmpresaService(MVCTesteContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
   ...
}
```

Controller:

```
public class EmpresasController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmpresaService _repo;

    public EmpresasController(IEmpresaService repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
....
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Não esqueceu de fazer a injeção de `MVCTesteContext`?

Comment: @LINQ Acredito que não deva ser. Pelo que estou entendendo ele esta achando que a interface é uma classe e que não tem um construtor publico(que é lógico por ser um interface)